# Want to match all non numbers is Arabic and English

Tags: regex

I want to match all non-numbers in English and Arabic, this is what I have so far: (but it is still not working as expected)

`([^0-9])([^\u0660-\u0669])`

[DEMO LINK](https://regex101.com/r/jI6gE8/7)

The String look like the following

***osama1234456789stringnew2123
اسامه١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨***

i want to get match only the numbers( arabic and english )

Comment: Could you please provide more details. Trying to understand more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for [Arabic script in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) shows the range for Arabic digits is `U+0660..U+0669` and `U+06F0..U+06F9`.

The whole range must be within **one** [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

I will assume you're coding in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), based on the link you posted. To replace each character except Arabic digits and 0-9, use the following expression:

**Regex:**

```
/[^0-9\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]+/g
```

```js
var re = /[^0-9\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]+/g;
var str = 'osama1234456789stringnew2123 اسامه١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨';
var subst = '';
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
document.write(result);
```

- Other regex flavors don't support the `\u0660` syntax. In PCRE, for example, use the `\x{0660}` notation.

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xO8iH9/1)</kbd>

Answer (score -3):

Use \D, which will match everything except digits.